# Wicket 7 - Web Sockets - EAP 6.3

Tags: websocket, jboss-eap-6, wicket-6

I'm trying to implement Websockets in Wicket 7 (EAP 6.3 environment) following this [mini-tutorial](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/nativewebsockets.html).

Everything is working as expected, except for the websocket is automatically closed after 60 seconds of inactivity. I've read in different places that I have to change the idle timeout for keeping the websocket open, but I can't find where to set the timeout in the Wicket implementation.

Another solution would be to send an empty message for keeping the connection alive, but I don't want this approach.

Did anyone find this problem working with websockets in Wicket 7?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but maybe you can use 'ping' message to keep the connection alive[RemoteEndpoint#sendPing()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/RemoteEndpoint.html#sendPing-java.nio.ByteBuffer-)

At the moment Wicket doesn't expose this API but if you confirm that it does the job then please create a ticket at [Apache JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET) and we will add it.

Comment: Thanks @margin-g, I used a rudimentary ping every 30 seconds with a fixed message to ignore it in the server side, that worked well. I didn't know how to implement what you said, but knowing that the ping was the way to go, it helped. Thanks.